# GCC - expected unqualified-id before 'using'

Tags: c++, gcc

> I want make alias of pointer on template struct, but it doesn't work.
>   Compiler version: gcc version 5.4.0 
>   Error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’ using pointer_Struct = *new_Struct;

Code example:

```
template<typename T>
class new_Struct
{
    T data;
};

template<typename T>
using pointer_Struct = new_Struct<T>*;


int main()
{  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `*` needs to be after the type, not before. `using pointer_Struct = new_Struct<T>*;`

Comment: @RSahu, make sence, but it doesn't work)

Comment: Works for me. https://ideone.com/ikMlqu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is currently correct, but you need to pass `-std=c++11` or higher to the compiler.